# Gaussian distribution for censored regression with cenreg

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis

I am trying to use the `cenreg` function in the `NADA` package in `R` to run a censored regression with a Gaussian distribution. The function works with a log-normal distribution, but returns an error when I try to use the Gaussian distribution.

Here is reproducible example with dummy data:

```
## Simulate data
d <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, times = 3))
d$conc <- d$x * 2 + rnorm(30, 0, sd = 0.25)
d$group <- rep(1:3, each = 10)
d$conc <- d$conc + d$group
d$group <- as.factor(d$group)
d$conc[ d$conc < 8] <- 0
d$conc <- d$conc + .01
d$cen <- FALSE
d$cen[ d$conc < 8] <- TRUE

library(NADA)
## Fit model with log-normal distribution 
m1 <- with(d, cenreg(Cen(conc, cen) ~ x + group - 1,
                     dist = 'lognormal'))
m1
## attempt to fit model with Gaussian distribution
m2 <- with(d, cenreg(Cen(conc, cen) ~ x + group - 1,
                     dist = 'gaussian'))
```

which gives me this error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found

I am using `R` version 3.2.3 and `NADA` version 1.5.6. This is the most recent version of the `NADA` package.

How do I use the `cenreg` function with a Gaussian distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug, but this works:

```
cenreg(Cen(d$conc, d$cen) ~ d$x + d$group - 1, dist = 'gaussian')
```

Comment: Yep, this code works :-). I through I tried this as well, but mustn't have. BTW, I was originally using a `data.table` and getting similar error messages.